# query to check if value exist in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the below columns

```
TableX

TB1_ID
TB_GO_ID
TB_RET_ID

TB1_ID  TB_GO_ID    TB_RET_ID
1   22  NULL
2   23  24
3   25  null
```

and another table TABLEY with

```
TB2
TB_ID

TB2_ID  TB_ID
1   22
2   22
3   23
4   24
```

my attempt

```
SELECT  
TB1_ID,
isexist
FROM TABLEX r,TABLEY Y where  Y.TB_ID in (R.TB_GO_ID, R.TB_RET_ID)
```

Expected output

```
TB1_ID  Isexist 
1   yes 
2   yes 
3   FALSE
```

Here isexist is  depends on if this id TB_GO_ID/TB_RET_ID exist in TABLEX SET THIS VALUE TO 1 else set this to 0.

i have written query like below to get the id from tablex and a variable field which determines if TB_GO_ID,TB_ret_ID exist in the second table. i am expecting a single row with the details of table x and a new field which says if the ids exist in the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` with a correlated sub-query inside a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT tb1_id,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1
                    FROM   TableY y
                    WHERE  y.tb_id = x.tb_go_id
                    OR     y.tb_id = x.tb_ret_id )
       THEN 'yes'
       ELSE 'false'
       END AS is_exist
FROM   TableX x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableX (TB1_ID, TB_GO_ID, TB_RET_ID) AS
SELECT 1, 22, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 23, 24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 25, NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TableY (TB2_ID, TB_ID) AS
SELECT 1, 22 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 24 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TB1_ID | IS_EXIST |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | yes |
| 2 | yes |
| 3 | false |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ltFJu3zk)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what 1, 2, 3 represent in expected output; I thought that these should've been values in TB_GO_ID and TB_RET_ID.

Presuming I'm right, then:

sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  tablex (tb1_id, tb_go_id, tb_ret_id) as
  3    (select 1, 22, null from dual union all
  4     select 2, 23, 24   from dual union all
  5     select 3, 25, null from dual
  6    ),
  7  tabley (tb2, tb_id) as
  8    (select 1, 22 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 22 from dual union all
 10     select 3, 23 from dual union all
 11     select 4, 24 from dual
 12    ),
```

Query begins here: `temp` CTE creates list of unique non-null ID values stored in both `TB_GO_ID` and `TB_RET_ID`:

```
 13  --
 14  temp as
 15    (select tb1_id, tb_go_id tb_goret_id from tablex where tb_go_id  is not null
 16     union
 17     select tb1_id, tb_ret_id            from tablex  where tb_ret_id is not null
 18    )
```

Finally, check whether `temp` `ID`s exist in `tabley`:

```
 19  select distinct t.tb1_id,
 20    case when y.tb_id is not null then 'yes' else 'no' end isexist
 21  from temp t left join tabley y on y.tb_id = t.tb_goret_id
 22  order by t.tb1_id;

    TB1_ID ISEXIST
---------- ----------
         1 yes
         2 yes
         3 no          --> NO, because 25 does not exist in TABLEY

SQL>
```

Comment: 1,2,3  is TB1_ID since 25 is not in the second table the value of ifexist is false here

Comment: OK, no big difference, just select another column. Fixed, have a look.

Comment: can we achieve this in simple query?

Comment: Isn't that *simple*? What's complex in it?

Comment: actually i am migrating data from old db to a new db where there is a structure/schema change in all the tables and there are around 25 tables. so i am trying to reduce the number of lines .

Comment: I see; can't tell, really. You could put everything I wrote (and you might use) between lines #14-22 into a loooong single line, so you'd reduce code into only one line, but I'm not sure that it would make any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data :

```
select *,
case when TB_GO_ID in (select tb_id from TableY) then 'Yes' 
when TB_RET_ID in (select tb_id from TableY) then 'Yes' else 'No' End as IF_Exists  
from tablex
```

Output As Below :

```
1   22   NULL   Yes
2   23   24     Yes
3   25   NULL   No
4   NULL 26     No
```